# Robot Framework equivalent of pytest.fixture

Tags: robotframework, pytest

A feature I like a lot with pytest is [pytest.fixture](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) which permits dependency injection.  As an example, I can have a fixture injecting a new random string `silly_string` into any function needing it:

**conftest.py:**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def silly_string(request):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(5))
```

**test_strings.py**

```
def test_string_length(self, silly_string)
    assert len(silly_string) == 5
```

Contrived example, obviously.

I am not aware of any equivalent functionality within Robot Framework.  Currently, I create a new variable using a keyword, and then pass that variable as a parameter.  It would be nice to have the parameter automatically injected.

Is there a mechanism within Robot Framework to similarly perform dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing built-in to robot to do what you want.

If what you're after is strings generated at runtime, you can leverage robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.4#extended-variable-syntax). For example, if you have a robot variable `${v}` that holds a reference to a python object, you can do something like this:

```
| | ${v}= | Get reference to v
| | log | Hello ${v.silly_string()}`
```

The above will call the `silly_string` method on the object pointed to by `${v}`. The keyword `Get reference to v` would be a python-based keyword that you write that returns an object with the `silly_string` method.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I don't suppose there's any way that you know of that Robot Framework and pytest can work together, pytest providing the dependency injection and Robot Framework handling the execution?

Comment: @alkalinity: I don't know. I've never used pytest before.